# Cannot link my form information with the User

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a edit page which you can edit your personal information that you register, such as username, first_name, last_name, email. But inside the page i have some extra field such as description, city, website field that you can add/edit into your profile if you wanted to.But after i edit the personal info and fill in the extra field for testing and press the confirm button, the personal information being edit succesfully and there is no error occur. But the problem is  when i check the data at Django admin, the UserExtraField model is empty. I hope my explanation is good enough.

the problem is i cant save the extra field to the user that login, but the personal information edit work fine, just the extra field cannot be save to the person. i want the user able to edit their personal profile and also add/edit the extra field if they want to.when they edit their personal profile, i want to add some field so they can have more information in their profile.

there is a picture link at the below too.Thank you.

views.py file

```
def UserProfileEdit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_edit = EditForm(request.POST, instance= request.user)
        form_extra = UserExtra(request.POST,instance=request.user)

        if form_edit.is_valid() and form_extra.is_valid():
            edit = form_edit.save()
            extra = form_extra.save()
            extra.user = edit
            return redirect('/userprofile/user')
    else:
        form_edit = EditForm(instance = request.user)
        form_extra = UserExtra(instance = request.user)
        user_edit = {'form_edit':form_edit,'form_extra':form_extra}
        return render(request,'user_profile/user_edit.html',context=user_edit)
```

forms.py

```
class EditForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', "password")

#make another forms for extra profile imformation
class UserExtra(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = UserExtraProfile
        fields = ('description','city','website')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
# Create your models here.


class UserExtraProfile(models.Model):
    #inherit the User model pk
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length= 250,default= '')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250,default= '')
    website = models.URLField(blank= True,default= '')
    # image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/profile_pic', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

def create_profile(sender,**kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserExtraProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])
post_save.connect(create_profile, sender = User)
```

user_edit.html

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <h1>User Profile Edit</h1>
  <form  method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form_edit %}
    {% bootstrap_form form_extra %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Confirm">

  </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4z7Mm.png)

Comment: Maybe I missed it in the description, but what's going wrong? Are you getting an error? Are the DB entries not associated with each other properly? Or something else?

Comment: Do not use two seperate forms. Create a new form for extra fields or make UserExtra extend EditForm.

Comment: @wholevinski , i have add some explaination in the first paragraph. Hopefully is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't save the extraprofile after assigning the user. Use `commit=False` in the form save so you don't hit the db twice.

```
user = form_edit.save()
extra = form_extra.save(commit=False)
extra.user = user
extra.save()
```

Also, you need to pass the profile, not the user, to the profile form.

```
form_extra = UserExtra(request.POST, instance=request.user.userextraprofile)
```